# Direct link to cPanel File Manager

Tags: cpanel

What is the direct link to the cPanel File Manager? The documentation says when inside cPanel, to access files, you have to click on the File Manager icon.

I can log in to cPanel but the page does not seem to go to cPanel. I need to upload some files on the server but somehow I cannot.

What I need is the link that gets you to the File Manager interface.

For example: To go directly to phpMyAdmin, you can type something like:

> example.com:XXXX/cpsess7168629484/3rdparty/phpMyAdmin/index.php

and this will send you directly to phpMyAdmin.

What if you want to go directly to File Manager?

Answer (score 1):

```
domain/IP : port / cPanel Security Token(if enabled) / frontend/x3/filemanager/index.html
```

So should look like this with cPanel Security token enabled:

```
http://example.com:2082/cpsess1234567/frontend/x3/filemanager/index.html
```

Or this without:

```
http://example.com:2082/frontend/x3/filemanager/index.html
```

Of course you will have to already be logged in or it will prompt you to do so.